# Home Premium OA to Ultimate via SP1

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have licensed Windows 7 Home Premium OA (OA means OEM Activated, i.e. Windows was installed and activated when i bought the laptop). Few months ago, i accidentally applied Windows 7 SP1 Ultimate without realizing that my edition is Home Premium OA, I got SP1 from a friend along with key. It got applied successfully and now my Windows edition is Windows 7 Ultimate SP1.

Few days ago, I executed Windows Updates and these worked as well.

Now i suddenly got message that my Windows is not activated. While activating, it is neither accepting Ultimate nor Home Premium OA key.

[image]

**Q 1:** Is it that easier to go Ultimate from Home Premium or is it a bug or what?

**Q 2:** How to activate now?

Comment: You will have to remind me. What does OA stand for exactly in this context? When you go to System Properties what is displayed. It would be helpful if you provided a screenshot, remove any personal information and license information from the screenshot, so you don't leak anything important.

Comment: @Ramhound Please see updated question

Comment: Looks to me like you upgraded, not just applied SP1.

Comment: @CharlieRB - Which is what he wants.  You will need to use the Phone Activation option to activate your installation.  The method you used was the correct way, I can't explain the reason it didn't actually activate, but it was never activated ( despite you thinking it was ) I know this because you only have 4 days left to activate.

Comment: @Ramhound I understood it as just wanting to apply SP1. After reading it again, it's not really clear the intent to upgrade or just apply the service pack.

Comment: @Ramhound No, it was not an upgrade, i was not intending to upgrade but just apply SP1. It was 9 days when i initially got the message that my windows is not activated.

Comment: @bjan - You can't type a `Windows 7 Ultimate` and "install" Service Pack 1 if Home Premium is installed without upgrading the system to Windows 7 Ultimate. You upgraded your system, the system properties proves this fact, your system is not a Windows 7 Ultimate installation ( there is no going back from this without a complete reinstallation of Home Premium ). Why wouldn't you just install Service Pack 1 through Windows Update if that was your goal? If you don't have a Windows 7 Ultimate key yourself you need one or choose to install Home Premium using the license key provided by your OEM.

Comment: @Ramhound :) I just installed SP1 Ultimate. I didn't upgraded to Ultimate, in doing so i would have license key which i didn't. I got SP1 along with Key and i just applied SP1. I don't apply SPs through Windows Update, i used to download SPs and then apply. You mean there is no way other than new Key or new Installation, right? As I know, Windows 7 new licenses have been stopped.

Comment: @bjan - They can still be purchased. Amazon still sells them. I don't know what you think you did but you upgraded your installation to Windows 7 Ultimate. **There is no question about that your screenshot proves it.** In the future just use Windows Update. Do yourself a favor create an .ISO of the disk you were loaned, change the disk to Home Premium, and keep it for later.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain that Stack Exchange doesn't want us helping you violate licensing.  You should have bought your own copy of Windows 7 Ultimate.  I understand it may have been a mistake but when you accidentally take something you shouldn't you should take responsibility and return it - or in the case of inappropriately used software, uninstalled/removed.  In this case, you should backup all your data and re-install your Windows 7 Home Edition.  Then use Windows Update to appropriately update Windows.  This should apply Service Pack 1 too, though you may have several rounds of Windows Updates to do. Then re-install your applications.

Comment: What about downgrading? Can i just uninstall SP and it will downgrade to Home Premium?

Comment: The problem is you did NOT install the service pack you installed Windows 7 Ultimate WITH Service Pack 1.  Service Packs are not distributed for specific editions of Windows.  Service Pack 1 for Windows 7 applies to ALL Windows 7 editions of the same language as the service pack.

Downgrading is not possible.  If you created a backup before you did this, you could restore your backup.